# php7 mongodb authentication fails

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, php-7

I have installed a php7 + mongodb 3.2 in an ubuntu stack:

pecl install mongodb (this is the new driver for `> 5.99.99`)

I'm also using the last php package [mongodb/mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) as wrapper.

but I have problems to authenticate the user.

```
new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://root:123456@somehost:27017');
```

it fails due the authentication mechanism, the driver is trying to authenticate as `MONGODB-CR` (deprecated in > 3.0) instead of `SCRAM-SHA-1`

Of course, the authentication works well with a shell mongo client:

```
mongo someip:27017/admin -u root -p "123456"
```

The question is, how can I specify the authentication mechanism in the php driver? (The `\MongoDB\Client` constructor accepts some array `$driverOptions = []`), is there any option to specify it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the latest driver. As the new default should have been [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/).

I ran a test under environment: php7, ubuntu14, [MongoDB v3.2.x](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production), [mongo-php-library =^1.0.0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) and [mongodb php driver v1.1.5](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb). Which works as expected.

```php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://user:pwd@host:port/admin");
$collection = $client->selectCollection("databaseName", "collection");
$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $document) { var_dump($document); }
```

I've also tested [authMechanism](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authMechanism) option in the URI, for example:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://user:pwd@host:port/admin?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1");
```

Which also works, although you shouldn't need to specify SCRAM-SHA-1 if you are using the new PHP driver. If you run `php --ri mongodb` you should be seeing something similar to (for v1.1.5):

```
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.5
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.3
libbson version => 1.3.3
```